# c++ How many classes should I make?

Tags: c++, class

I'm practicing with classes and I'm given the task of creating employee management system. I'm given two .txt files. One (details.txt) has details of each employee with the following info: ID, name, DOB, SSN, department, and position. A sample of the file looks like such:

> 5 ali 6/24/1988 126-42-6989 support assistant
>
> 13 tim 2/10/1981 131-12-1034 logistics manager

The other .txt (timelog.txt) will contain a daily log of when employees clock in and clock out. The following format for this file is: ID, date, clock in time, and clock out time. Sample:

> 5 3/11 0800 1800
>
> 13 3/11 0830 1830

Firstly, I am to allow users to search up an employee by ID, name, department or position. Doing so will display all of the employees info (multiple employees if they have the same name, position or are from the same department) as well as show the total number of hours they have worked in the company.

Secondly, users are to be given another option to look up employee time logs by ID number. This will display the entire clock in/ clock out history of that employee as well as total hours worked each day.

I'm planning to read in the info from .txt files via ifstream and store them as an array of objects. I'm just wondering how many classes I should create. I'm thinking 2 classes- one for employee info (from details.txt) and one for time logs(timelogs.txt). Is there any other class I should create or should those 2 suffice?

Comment: This is very broad and subject to many different answers: there is no clear, perfect way to perform what you want, but there are many good ways of doing it and many bad ways. That being said, consider starting with some UML and class diagrams

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:** At least two.

**Long answer:** It depends on many things. Especially what part of code you can identify as potentially reusable.

If you asked for the highest possible amount of classes that could accomplish your task, I would think about a single class for:

- Employee
- EmployeeManager (Factory, Holder etc.) – creates, holds and deletes the Employee objects, provides search feature
- DayWork – a row from `timelog.txt`, can calculate the amount of hours/minutes spent in work that day
- WorkLog – a list of DayWork objects for one employee, can calculate the whole spent time
- TextLineParser – encapsulation of `std::ifstream`

The right answer is most likely somewhere between. Keep in mind that C++ is a multi-paradigm language and you can perform some operations without having a class for them. Instead, they can be performed in a function or a set of functions in a C-like unit. That’s especially useful for one-time operations where the functions don’t share common data (potential properties).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm planning on creating functions to search within the object array once I create one for each employee . I'm also going to create a function that'll calculate total time worked for the day and total time overall.